# Magento 2 GraphQl + Elasticsearch 6, GraphQl query products do not run pass by elasticsearch

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch, graphql

I have a problem with query:

```
    {
      products(
        filter: { sku: { like: "24-WB%" } }
      ) {
        items {
          sku
        }
      }
    }
```

Although using search engine is "elasticsearch", it still using mysql. I dont know why? Please give me solution. 
Thanks everyone for reading.

Comment: what is the error coming after running the qraphql query

Comment: @Mujahidh . 
When i debug, I recognized data is returned not via Elasticsearch

Comment: @Mujahidh
processing flow go to Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Adapter::query()  instead of
\Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\SearchAdapter\Adapter::query

Comment: ... up up post post